# Redirect traffic to external proxy using iptables

Tags: iptables

Currently what I have tried is

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -j DNAT -i ens3 --to-destination proxy-ip:19012

sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING --dst proxy-ip -p udp --dport 19012 -j SNAT --to-source server-ip
```

What I'm trying to do is forward outbound traffic to an external proxy and then have inbound traffic forwarded back to the appropriate processes.

What am I doing wrong?

edit:

After doing some reading I have concluded that I need to use OUTPUT instead of PREROUTING, but I don't know how to specify the destination address. The closest I have gotten is:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p udp -j REDIRECT --to-destination proxy-ip --to-port 19012
```

And this still does not answer the question of how to interpret inbound traffic.

Comment: @A.B I have all tcp traffic going to a local transparent proxy. I'm trying to do the same for udp.

Comment: destination information is lost. That's fine for HTTP where the information is (more or less) duplicated in the data, but for a random packet of a random application, I don't see how the transparent proxy will be able to forward it further with this. probably requires some kind of encapsulation, tunnel etc.

Comment: @A.B would tproxy be of use in this case?

Comment: no TPROXY as per the documentation doesn't apply for local traffic (and would still require a local application as tunnel endpoint probably). There could be creative ways using network namespaces to use it. Anyway any solution will involve some routing tweaking, not just iptables

Comment: @A.B Could it be done without setting up a server? Just a client I mean. I could try to write something up

Comment: You need to clearly define the expected behavior of the system in order to actually implement such system. For example, client A sends UDP packet from port X to destinaion B port Y. What would the exact packet flow be?